# JSON response's part to be displayed with a recylerView

Tags: android, json, cardview

I need to display a list of ingredients and measures from the JSON response. I know how to get 'category' and 'area' from the entire response. Although, I do not understand how to get the ingredients and measures(to be part of my recylerView that includes category, area, etc). I need to display recipes in different cardViews with all the ingredients and measures.

I have posted a snippet of the json response and my code. 
Thank you

**THIS IS THE JSON RESPONSE**

```
{"meals":[{"idMeal":"52956",
"strMeal":"Chicken Congee",
"strCategory":"Chicken",
"strArea":"Chinese",
"strInstructions":"STEP 1 - MARINATING THE CHICKEN\r\nIn a bowl, add chicken, salt, white pepper, ginger juice and then mix it together well.\r\nSet the chicken aside.\r\nSTEP 2 - RINSE THE WHITE RICE\r\nRinse the rice in a metal bowl or pot a couple times and then drain the water.\r\nSTEP 2 - BOILING THE WHITE RICE\r\nNext add 8 cups of water and then set the stove on high heat until it is boiling. Once rice porridge starts to boil, set the stove on low heat and then stir it once every 8-10 minutes for around 20-25 minutes.\r\nAfter 25 minutes, this is optional but you can add a little bit more water to make rice porridge to make it less thick or to your preference.\r\nNext add the marinated chicken to the rice porridge and leave the stove on low heat for another 10 minutes.\r\nAfter an additional 10 minutes add the green onions, sliced ginger, 1 pinch of salt, 1 pinch of white pepper and stir for 10 seconds.\r\nServe the rice porridge in a bowl\r\nOptional: add Coriander on top of the rice porridge.",
"strMealThumb":"https:\/\/www.themealdb.com\/images\/media\/meals\/1529446352.jpg","strTags":null,
"strYoutube":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=kqEfk801E94",

"strIngredient1":"Chicken","strIngredient2":"Salt","strIngredient3":"Pepper","strIngredient4":"Ginger Cordial","strIngredient5":"Ginger","strIngredient6":"Spring Onions","strIngredient7":"Rice","strIngredient8":"Water","strIngredient9":"Coriander","strIngredient10":"","strIngredient11":"","strIngredient12":"","strIngredient13":"","strIngredient14":"","strIngredient15":"","strIngredient16":"","strIngredient17":"","strIngredient18":"","strIngredient19":"","strIngredient20":"",

"strMeasure1":"8 oz ","strMeasure2":"pinch","strMeasure3":"pinch","strMeasure4":"1 tsp ","strMeasure5":"1 tsp ","strMeasure6":"1 tbs","strMeasure7":"1\/2 cup ","strMeasure8":"8 cups ","strMeasure9":"2 oz ","strMeasure10":"","strMeasure11":"","strMeasure12":"","strMeasure13":"","strMeasure14":"","strMeasure15":"","strMeasure16":"","strMeasure17":"","strMeasure18":"","strMeasure19":"","strMeasure20":"",
"strSource":"https:\/\/sueandgambo.com\/pages\/chicken-congee",
"dateModified":null},
{"idMeal":"52955",
"strMeal":"Egg Drop Soup",
"strCategory":"Vegetarian",
"strArea":"Chinese",
"strInstructions":"In a wok add chicken broth and wait for it to boil.\r\nNext add salt, sugar, white pepper, sesame seed oil.\r\nWhen the chicken broth is boiling add the vegetables to the wok.\r\nTo thicken the sauce, whisk together 1 Tablespoon of cornstarch and 2 Tablespoon of water in a bowl and slowly add to your soup until it's the right thickness.\r\nNext add 1 egg slightly beaten with a knife or fork and add it to the soup slowly and stir for 8 seconds\r\nServe the soup in a bowl and add the green onions on top.",
"strMealThumb":"https:\/\/www.themealdb.com\/images\/media\/meals\/1529446137.jpg",
"strTags":"Soup,Baking,Calorific",
"strYoutube":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=9XpzHm9QpZg",
"strIngredient1":"Chicken Stock","strIngredient2":"Salt","strIngredient3":"Sugar","strIngredient4":"Pepper","strIngredient5":"Sesame Seed Oil","strIngredient6":"Peas","strIngredient7":"Mushrooms","strIngredient8":"Cornstarch","strIngredient9":"Water","strIngredient10":"Spring Onions","strIngredient11":"","strIngredient12":"","strIngredient13":"","strIngredient14":"","strIngredient15":"","strIngredient16":"","strIngredient17":"","strIngredient18":"","strIngredient19":"","strIngredient20":"",
"strMeasure1":"3 cups ","strMeasure2":"1\/4 tsp","strMeasure3":"1\/4 tsp","strMeasure4":"pinch","strMeasure5":"1 tsp ","strMeasure6":"1\/3 cup","strMeasure7":"1\/3 cup","strMeasure8":"1 tbs","strMeasure9":"2 tbs","strMeasure10":"1\/4 cup","strMeasure11":"","strMeasure12":"","strMeasure13":"","strMeasure14":"","strMeasure15":"","strMeasure16":"","strMeasure17":"","strMeasure18":"","strMeasure19":"","strMeasure20":"","strSource":"https:\/\/sueandgambo.com\/pages\/egg-drop-soup","dateModified":null}
```

**THIS IS MY METHOD TO OBTAIN THE CONTENTS FROM THE JSON RESPONSE THAT DOESN'T SEEM TO WORK FOR INMGREDIENTS**

I TRIED TWO **FOR LOOPS**, BUT I DOES NOT WORK

```
private void loadRecylerViewData () {

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_DATA,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("meals");
                        String hello;
                        String ing = "strIngredient";
                        ArrayList<String> listIng = new ArrayList<>();

                        Log.e(" " + jsonArray.length(), "error");
                        for (int i = 0; i < (jsonArray.length()); i++) {

                            JSONObject o = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


                             for (int n = 1; n <= 20; n++)
                            {

                                hello = ing.concat(Integer.toString(n));
                                listIng.add( o.getString(hello));

                            }
                            element e = new element(o.getString("strCategory"), o.getString("strMealThumb "),
                                    listIng);
                            elementList.add(e);
                        }


                        adapter = new recylerAdapter(elementList, getApplicationContext());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: Does it crash? you can try to use breakpoints and debug what is hapenning.

Comment: Whats the error

Comment: There's no error, the app doesn't crash either. I just can't figure out how to get all the ingredients and measures in one recipe with all the others(category, area, etc.)